# How to dinamically unbind all event handlers and rebind them after doing something?

Tags: delphi, event-handling

I'm looking for a common way to unbind all event handlers and rebind them again after doing something that would have triggered them.

Currently, I'm using specific solutions like the following:

```
var
  PrevBeforePost : TDataSetNotifyEvent;
  PrevAfterPost : TDataSetNotifyEvent;
begin
  PrevBeforePost := MyDataSet.BeforePost;
  MyDataSet.BeforePost := nil;
  PrevAfterPost := MyDataSet.AfterPost;
  MyDataSet.AfterPost := nil;

  try
    //do something that would have triggered event handlers
  finally
    MyDataSet.BeforePost := PrevBeforePost;
    MyDataSet.AfterPost := PrevAfterPost;
  end;
end;
```

This solution imply that I have to write specific code each time where I need to temporarly disable event handlers, even while I'm doing tests...
Furthermore, it's very easy to fall into the trap of adding other events without remembering to disable them in the code.

Is there a way to write a common solution which works in the same way for all components?
Example:

```
var
   Events : TInfosAboutEventHandlers;
begin
   Events := GetEventHandlersAndSetThemToNil(MyDataSet);
   try
     //do something that would have triggered event handlers
   finally
     SetEventHandlers(MyDataSet, Events);
   end;
end;
```

Comment: One wonders if there is perhaps a better solution to the problem .......

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean if you can solve your problem without having to screw around with the event handlers. I mean find a way to solve the underlying position without ever finding yourself needing to do this. On the other hand, if all you need to do is save away two event handlers, how hard can that be? If you want something that will work for all possible components, then one wonders why you are writing code that requires that in the first place.

Comment: I agree with David that this sounds like something strange to need. But as alternative you could setup a private boolean field and in every event do nothing when this field is true. In your code you can then set it to true so the events dont do anything and in the finally set it back to false so the events can do their thing again. It works but is quit a bit dirty

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I think it depends on the way each one likes to write its code. In most cases event handlers could be avoided in favour of different approaches, but I think there are too much scenarios and too much components for thinking everything can be done without event handlers and still keeping a clean code. There are several reasons why I'm asking about a common solution, as first, it would avoid to change the code each time a new event handler is assigned (Immagine you are editing a part of an application you've not edited since years, ...

Comment: ... it's really easy to forgot to unbind and rebind this event as done for the others). As last, it would save alot of time while testing (Quite often, I have more than 2 event handlers, refering to the question, it was just an example about the way I'm currently doing it). I personally prefer solutions which work in more possible cases and prefer to avoid specific solutions. A solution like that could make my code slimmer, safer, and quicker to write.

Comment: How would your general purpose code identify an event handler. Can you come up with a fool-proof characterisation of event handlers?

Comment: Usually if you need to skip handler calling you do that in handlers itself with FUpdate integer value. Like it is done with methods BeginUpdate/EndUpdate in most libraries. Setting and resetting to nil is not a clean solution.. As what if some code changes the event handler in between? So anyway its not clean way of doing that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I don't know how/if an event handler can be identified. I know you can get the property names and their values starting from a TObject (using GetPropInfos), but I don't know if there's a way to get event handlers.

Comment: Event handlers are just properties whose values are procedural types.  That's probably the best way to identify them but formally in the language, they are just properties.  You could certainly do this all with RTTI and a dictionary to hold the values.  If I were you I don't think I'd bother.  Feels opaque to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why instead of unbinding them don't you just disable them through a variable ?.

Define that "disabling" variable on your form, and activate it every time you want to avoid events.

```
type MyForm = class (TForm)
  ...
  private
     EventsDisabled: boolean;
  ...
end;

implementation
...
  EventsDisabled := True;
  try
    //do something that would have triggered event handlers
  finally
    EventsDisabled := False;
  end;
```

Now your events just have to check that that variable is not active before doing anything.

```
procedure TForm1.qryDataFieldNameOnChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if EventsDisabled then Exit;
  //actions to do when the event is triggered 
end;
```